# RSpec test for a module

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm brand new to RSpec and TDD. I was wondering if someone might help me with creating a test well-suited for this Module:

```
module Kernel
  # define new 'puts' which which appends "This will be appended!" to all puts output 
  def puts_with_append *args
    puts_without_append args.map{|a| a + "This will be appended!"}
  end

  # back up name of old puts
  alias_method :puts_without_append, :puts

  # now set our version as new puts
  alias_method :puts, :puts_with_append
end
```

I'd like for my test to check that the content from a 'puts' ends with "This will be appended!". Would that be a sufficient test? How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best tests test what you're trying to achieve, not how you achieve it... Tying tests to implementation makes your tests brittle.

So, what you're trying to achieve with this method is a change to "puts" whenever your extension is loaded.  Testing the method puts_with_append doesn't achieve this goal... If you later accidentally re-alias that to something else, your desired puts change won't work.

However, testing this without using an implementation detail would be rather difficult, so instead, we can try to push the implementation details down to somewhere they won't change, like *STDOUT*.

### Just the Test Content

```
$stdout.stub!(:write)
$stdout.should_receive(:write).with("OneThis will be appended!")
puts "One"
```

### Full Test

I'm going to turn this into a blog post within the next day or so, but I think you should also consider that you've got a desired result for one and many arguments, and your tests should be easy to read.  The ultimate structure I'd use is:

require "rspec"
require "./your_extention.rb"

```
describe Kernel do
  describe "#puts (overridden)" do
    context "with one argument" do
      it "should append the appropriate string" do
        $stdout.stub!(:write)
        $stdout.should_receive(:write).with("OneThis will be appended!")
        puts "One"
      end
    end

    context "with more then one argument" do
      it "should append the appropriate string to every arg" do
        $stdout.stub!(:write)
        $stdout.should_receive(:write).with("OneThis will be appended!")
        $stdout.should_receive(:write).with("TwoThis will be appended!")
        puts("One", "Two")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow - very helpful! Would you mind posting a link to your blogpost here when you're done with it? Thanks!